# Make api calls to custom heroku domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, heroku, subdomain

I'm building an open API with rails and hosting my project on Heroku. However I want my API calls to be from mydomain.co instead of heroku's domain.

I added my domain from Heroku dashboard, and I also forwarded my domain to heroku's url.

However when I make the 'POST' call like below:

```
 curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"myjsontitle":{"field1":"eerbil.eren@derivalabs.com","field2":"12345678"}}' -X POST http://deriva.co/applicants.json
```

Terminal returns the following:

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://stark-bayou-1773.herokuapp.com/applicants.json">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

And when I look at the heroku logs, it says

```
at=info method=GET path="/applicants.json" host=stark-bayou-1773.herokuapp.com
```

How should I fix that problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is an error with your DNS configuration.

```
➜  ~  curl -I deriva.co
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: https://stark-bayou-1773.herokuapp.com
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 02 Feb 2015 19:59:45 GMT
Content-Length: 155
Age: 67
Connection: keep-alive
```

`deriva.co` redirects to Heroku, whereas it should resolve to it. You probably used a sort of provider redirect, which is not the correct DNS configuration. You need to ["point" the DNS to Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#root-domain).

Please note that you can't map `deriva.co` to Heroku directly unless your providers supports a [CNAME-like configuration for the root domain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains). And GoDaddy does not.

You either need to [change DNS provider](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#root-domain) or point `www.deriva.co` using a CNAME and redirect `deriva.co` to `www.deriva.co`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works with www however it doesn't work with naked domain. my POST requests are sent as GET to heroku. How should I fix that?